# Force to use different user agent with js or axios

Tags: javascript, axios, user-agent

I am routing all requests through my axios get and post requests. I am testing some iframes which detect the user agent and depending on what agent it is, they change the payload and the style etc.

If I change it on dev tools by toggling device toolbar and setting to an iphone for example, all requests are coming with the correct user agent and all works good, nothing gets blocked, but if I pass my own user agent (the same which I copied from the ones being used by the device toolbar) and pass it as a custom axios header it kind of works but not really. The iframe detects its a device but requests are still blocked.

Is there a way to force to use another user agent via js or axios?

Currently I am using axios like this:

```
axios.get(req.originalUrl, { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1' }  }).then((response) => {
      res.send(response.data)
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can set `user-agent` with requests we're making by passing additonal arguments `options` to an axios call.

```js
let options = {
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'xyz-bla-bla'
  }
}

axios.get(req.originalUrl, data, options);   // setting request header, using options

//or 

axios.get(req.originalUrl, data, options).then((response) => {
  //res.header({'key':'value'})     //set response header, if necessary
  res.send(response.data);
});
```

Remember to distinguish between **response header**, and **request header**.

Comment: In my testing, Chrome (for example) overrides this header to its own value no matter what you ask Axios to send, so no dice on this solution.

Comment: are you using selenium something?

Comment: Just testing with Axios from browser.