# async axios get call axios returns nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, axios

I'm trying to get the current temperature from [openweathermaps](https://openweathermap.org/api) using `axios`.

I can put my url into the browser and it works fine. But when I try do an axios call with the correct url it doesnt event call.

Here is the relevant code section:

```js
function Overview() {
  const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState('')
  const API_KEY = '{apikey}'

  const getTemperature = useCallback(async () => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude.toFixed(2)}&lon=${longitude.toFixed(
      2,
    )}&appid=${API_KEY}`

    console.log('my provided url is set to:', url)

    const response = await axios.get(url)
    if (response.data) {
      setTemperature(response.data.main.temp)
    }
  }, [latitude, longitude])

  useEffect(() => {
    getTemperature().catch(console.error)
  }, [getTemperature])

  return <>{temperature ? temperature : 'no data'}</>
}
```

Any help as to where I'm going wrong would be great as I just cant see my error!

Comment: Unrelated to you post: can you replace your API key with a fake or remove from post for security reasons at least?

Comment: Other quick questions: Why do you await again a sync response in `await response.data?.main?.temp`? Do the API expected that encoded URI format?

Comment: Ive just updated to what I originally had, I had been doing some tests

Comment: Setting an user agent could help,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67486713/2122822
also try to see what headers that send in the request that is working

Comment: You have declared a function called `setTemperature` (`const setTemperature = async () => {}`), however are trying to call a function called getTemperature (`useEffect(() => {getTemperature()}, [latitude, longitude])`). Maybe this is just your example code and not your actual code? Also note that `setTemperature` will already exists because it's part of your `const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState('');`

Comment: It's a typo @devklick. I edited the question for him early on. Thanks for pointing out. Edit queue is full right now, but will correct it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL working on the browser showcases that your API key is correct. Now, make sure the  variables in your URL are properly set from the code, particularly the API key. you can console.log them to be sure. Passed that, the minimal code below would do.

```js
import {useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Overview() {

// YOUR_INITIAL_STATE rather be undefined 
const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState(YOUR_INITIAL_STATE);

const API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

const getTemperature = useCallback(async () => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`;

   console.log("my provided url is set to:", url);

    const response = await axios.get(url);
    if(response.data){
      setTemperature(response.data.main.temp);
    }
// only call the functtion when these deps change
}, [latitude, longitude])

useEffect(() => {
// Check the error for further debbugging
getTemperature()
.catch(console.error);

}, [getTemperature])

      return (
            <>
          {temperature ? temperature : "no data"} 
            </>
        );
}
```

Comment: Hey unfortunately this still is failing and I have no clue why, im logging the same url as is in my browser but its still not working. Could it be to do with the fact its react native and expo? I am beyond confused

Comment: To make it more bizarre, I just ran this in an empty react project and it works? Maybe its something to do with react native and expo?

Comment: You can always run the code on  a bare [react-expo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-71063538-react-expo-weather-forked-egyi9) project on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) to clear your doubts. Passed that, you'll need to provide more context for people to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your arrow function is calling itself recursively:

```
const setTemperature = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`);
    setTemperature(response.data.main.temp);
};
```

Your code doesn't show where this is being called.  Probably it needs to be something like:

```
const setTemperature = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`);
    return response.data.main.temp;
};
```

Perhaps it just needs to be a one letter change:

```
const getTemperature = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`);
    setTemperature(response.data.main.temp);
};
```

Credit to @devklick

Comment: Hi! I just tried the answer above and I think its something to do with expo and using expo instead of my ip! As I tried to rerun this in a local react project and it worked fine. I found some similar questions on stack overflow which suggest to run the query against my ip!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't answer the question on expo vs your ip.  AFAICT the recursive call shouldn't work anywhere.  Based on the comment from @devklick you might just need to change `const setTemperature = async () => {` to `const getTemperature = async () => {`

Comment: @David, that was a typo I made when editing his question and is in no case found in its original question. Thanks for pointing it out. It's has been fixed by another editor.