# (node:78) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failedwith status code 502

Tags: axios, cheerio

I am getting request failed with status code 502. I am trying to web scrape this page to get data from the home page and display it to a frontend website that I am building but I can't get the raw html for the life of me.

```
  const express = require("express");
  const cheerio = require("cheerio");
  const axios = require("axios");

  const app = express();

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  const website = "https://und.com";

  try {
    axios(website).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);

      let content = [];

      $(".sdc-site-tile__headline", data).each(function () {
        const title = $(this).text();
        const url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

        content.push({
          title,
          url
        });

        app.get("/", (req, res) => {
          res.json(content);
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, error.message);
  }

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on PORT:${PORT}`);
  });
```

Comment: That is very true I will remove the tag! Any help you can provide on why this code is not console logging anything?

Comment: You're probably being blocked or the thing you want is injected by JS. If I `view-source:` on that page, I see no such `sdc-site-tile__headline` anywhere in the document.

Comment: I have updated the code and am still getting no console log

Comment: No console log whatsoever? I see the cheerio object logged, although I can't imagine why that'd be informative... What data are you trying to get exactly? BTW, your update with the user-agent invalidated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755490/6243352), so please try to focus on keeping the Q&A flow clear to future visitors. The point is to curate a resource rather than use the site as an interactive help desk. Please ask a new question if the existing answer solved your original problem, the 502 error.

Comment: I totally understand I will ask a new question! I am trying to get the news headlines off of und.com to display on my own website.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, your try/catch doesn't catch errors in the `.then` promise chain. You have to use `.catch()` to catch `then` errors, or switch to `async`/`await`. Express is also sort of irrelevant to the question here, so I'd just focus on axios and cheerio. Once you have the data, you'll have no problem returning it as a response. Removing unnecessary distractions makes it easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

This question needs more information. A 502 HTTP error means the following:

"The 502 error is one of the status codes, which indicates that the web server you've connected to is serving as a proxy for data relayed from another server, but that server has returned an invalid response."

Since you are trying to scrape a website it is likely that you are being blocked. This might be due to your user agent containing flags that are sniffed by their servers and thus blocked.

You can change your user agent to something that shows you are an actual browser. Try passing a user agent in your http header.

Here's a link for adding header options with Axios:

[Force to use different user agent with js or axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630953/force-to-use-different-user-agent-with-js-or-axios)

Comment: What other information would you like me to provide?

Comment: I have updated the code above to what I am now running and I no longer get the 502 error but nothing seems to console log

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755490/6243352) which suggests a user agent to avoid the 502 response, it sounds like you want the selector `".post__meta h3 a:last-child"`:

```js
const axios = require("axios"); // ^0.21.4
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const website = "https://und.com";
const options = {
  headers: {
    "user-agent":
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
  },
};

axios(website, options)
  .then(({data}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const result = $(".post__meta h3 a:last-child")
      .map((_, e) => $(e).text().trim())
      .get();
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Note that `try`/`catch` doesn't work with `.then`:

```js
// wrong (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch)
try {
  fetch("wrong")
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text));
}
catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}

// correct
fetch("wrong")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

// correct
(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("wrong");
    const text = await res.text();
    console.log(text);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. How would I also bring in the picture and have link to the actual page that is being shown?

Comment: Please give it a try, then ask a new question if you get stuck and show a [mcve] of that attempt. I'll be happy to help. Otherwise, the thread just devolves into endless goalpost-moving requirements, which is treating the site like a live help desk. That's not the intent--it's a focused Q&A--one question. Already, this answer is getting ahead of itself because the real question here is a 502 error with axios. Thanks.

Comment: I just posted a new comment I am close to what I need to do but having another error if you dont mind can you check my new question